# Help needed while setting up basic multiplatform cmake-enabled project

Tags: c++, header, makefile, cmake, project-structure

**tl;dr the questions are at the bottom.**

I am a developer trying something new - my last poison is c++. As I am spending half of my time on my linux laptop and the other half on Win XP PC, I tried to find a way to create basic, barebone project, using good c++ practices (well, I don't know them from experience, I just read about them). Right now my project almost works while using `cmake . && make` on linux (it works when header and source files are in the same folder, fails when I separate them to include / src folders). I am using nuwen's distribution of mingw on windows (and I know that the toolchain is working, it compiles projects from within Eclipse without any problems).

My project directory looks like this:

```
engine 
    |
    |- main
         |
         |- include
                 |
                 |- App.h  
                 |- CMakeLists.txt (2)
         |- src
             |
             |- main.cc
             |- App.cc
             |- CMakeLists.txt (3)

    |- CMakLists.txt (1)
```

The contents of the files are very simple (I will remove the include guards, etc for clarity)

App.h:

```
class App {
   public:
      App();
      int onExecute();
};
```

App.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "App.h"

App::App() {
}

int App::onExecute() {
   std::cout << "inside app.." << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "App.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  App a;

  a.onExecute();
  std::cout << "inside main.." << '\n';
}
```

CMakeLists.txt (1) - the main one:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")

project (gameengine)

add_definitions ( "-Wall -ansi -pedantic")

add_subdirectory (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/include)
add_subdirectory (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/src)

add_executable (engine ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main/src/main.cc)
target_link_libraries (engine Application)
```

CMakeLists.txt (2) - inside the include directory

```
add_library (Application App)
set_target_properties (Application PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

CMakeLists.txt (3) - inside the src directory

```
include_directories (../include)
```

And this is as far as I got - with some changes (i.e. moving App.cc to the include directory) the whole thing compiles and runs fine on linux - but I can't get the mingw generator to work on Win XP. I hand tuned the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM in the file CMakeCache.txt to point to the proper make.exe (I know that this should be defined as a system variable but as I am working on many different PC's, I don't want to leave junk after me).

My questions are:

1) what are the guidelines for writing  multiplatform CMakeLists.txt file (which will work independly of the os and the location of the project files), which preferably will allow me to easy swich my project configuration from one os the other one?

2) how can I address the error of not finding the header file (make gives: (...)\engine\main\src\main.cc:2:17: fatal error: App.h: No such file or directory) ?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1) what are the guidelines for writing multiplatform CMakeLists.txt file (which will work independly of the os and the location of the project files), which preferably will allow me to easy swich my project configuration from one os the other one?

Well, I'm certainly no expert, but I can share my 10-month experience with a cross-platform cmake-based project.

Right off the bat I think you really should be using **out of source builds**. This means that you don't run cmake in the same directory where your code is; instead, you create a new folder, e.g. `engine/build` and run `cmake ../main` from there. This way you don't clobber your source files with cmake stuff, such as CMakeCache.txt etc. There are even some macros you can use to forbid your users from doing in-source builds.

I also find it useful to create a set of macro files to help set compiler options for different platforms. Here at work we have macros such as `ADD_GCC_FLAG` or `ADD_MSVC_FLAG` which check the current compiler and add flags accordingly.

I think it is good practice to have a single `.cmake` file which concentrates all your project configurations in one place. At work all our `CMakeLists.txt` start with `include( ../cmake/configs.cmake )`. This file sets all sorts of options, such as standard include directories, default compiler flags etc.

To assuage your problem with include directories, I suggest you use absolute rather than relative paths in your source files. Define a standard include directory, for instance `engine/main/include` and always `#include` files relative to that path. In your example, if you wanted to include `engine/main/include/somefolder/header.h`, you'd write `#include <somefolder/header.h>` (using `<>` instead of quotes tells the C++ preprocessor to skip the current directory when looking for the file).

---

> 2) how can I address the error of not finding the header file (make gives: (...)\engine\main\src\main.cc:2:17: fatal error: App.h: No such file or directory) ?

There are a number of issues with your cmake layout, but the reason you were getting that error is because you need to call `include_directories` in `CMakeLists.txt (1)` as well.

Besides that, your other `CMakeLists.txt` files have problems too. In `CMakeLists.txt (2)`, the arguments to `add_library` are wrong; it should be `../src/App.cc`, otherwise you're just adding an empty library. And you don't need that `set_target_properties` either, at least not if you got the `add_library` arguments right. You also need a `include_directory` call in that same `CMakeLists.txt` that's adding the library; putting it in `(3)` doesn't really do anything.

Actually, you don't need a `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `include` directory, since there's nothing to build there. It's better to put the `add_library` call in `CMakeLists.txt (3)`, right after calling `include_directories`.

I hope this clears some of your doubts.

Comment: Thank You very much for those advices. This is the kind of suggestions, which I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you expect but since you didn't stated whether you'd like alternative solutions, I will suggest it anyway:

For multi-platform projects I would recommend `SConstruct` which is really a great and flexible tool. I don't know CMake well so I can really provide a detailed comparison.

However, here are the reasons why I love this tool:

- It's Python. So you can do almost anything you want regarding customization and/or special needs
- It's really easy to learn and for simple projects, it takes only a few lines of code to get started.
- It depends solely on Python so on Linux its very often already installed and on Windows it take 5 minutes to download and install.
- It has a **very good** automatic dependency tree generation and parallel compilation support.

Comment: I think Scons has a lot of potential mainly because of the use of Python, but right now I'd say CMake is the most mature choice. We've been using it here at work for a Mac OS, Linux and Windows project, and it works wonders. The single fact that you can generate `.sln` files for VC++6.0 up to VC++10, plus Xcode and Eclipse project files is amazing.

Comment: @Pedro d'Aquino: I don't know CMake enough so I can't really talk about it. But I'm indeed convinced that it is a great tool and as you said, a mature choice. I believe SConstruct has no native support for generating `.sln` files. However this can be easily added.